# How set preferences error on editor Android Studio like Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, editor

How set preferences error on editor Android Studio like Eclipse ?

**Android Studio** (I add "X" by photosop)
[image]
**like eclipse**
[image]

thanks :)